# Why does r (r code) give me jagged line in my graph?

Tags: r, graphing

```
LocA<-(Graphdata[["Loc==AB"]])
plot(0, 0, xlim = c(1, 20), ylim = c(70, 200), asp=NA, xlab = "", ylab = "", type = "n")
lines(LocA$K,type="l",col="blue",lwd=2)
lines(LocA$L,type="l",col="green",lwd=2)
lines(LocA$M,type="l",col="red",lwd=2)
lines(LocA$N,type="l",col="orange",lwd=2)
```

And I want the x=axis to cover the range from 1:20 as it is given by xlim=C(1:20) but it doesn't extend to that range and the graph looks gagged and it doesn't go beyond 10 but it is supposed to cover the range given by D.[image] 
Part of the data and the graph for this data is given below:

```
    Loc D     K        L           M           N
1   AB  1  95.03813   110.4466        NA       NA
2   AB  3  82.36166   154.3045        NA       NA
3   AB  5  81.08041   118.5903        NA       NA
4   AB  7  82.40850   110.6272    87.89905       NA
5   AB  9  83.94922   105.1753        NA      82.28767
6   AB 11  84.94135   102.8754        NA      77.83648
7   AB 13  85.835855  101.209326  80.077513   75.355855 
8   AB 15  86.309016  100.978860  79.784663   75.128083 
9   AB 17  87.792539  99.914197  78.878135    75.121244
```

Comment: Your Y axis seems to just b the row index? You only have 9 values. You've set the x limits as ranging from 1 - 20, not that values should be 1:20. You need to tell the plot that those values should be from D

Comment: Your values seem to drop below 70, so you cannot see them.

Comment: I did that and it doesn't give me the graph and it resulted in an empty plot with only x and y-axis label

Answer (score 0):

as pointed out in zacdav's comment, you forgot to specify the independent variable for your lines, the x values.

For example, where you wrote:

`lines(LocA$K,type="l",col="blue",lwd=2)`

you should add also `LocA$D`, like this:

`lines(LocA$D, LocA$K,type="l",col="blue",lwd=2)`

for each of the line definition.

Comment: @llarioGelmetti It doesn't give me the graph and it resulted in empty plot with ony x and y axis label.

Comment: I think the way you're subsetting Graphdata is wrong, so you have an empty LocA. Try replacing `LocA<-(Graphdata[["Loc==AB"]])` with `LocA<-subset(Graphdata, Loc=="AB")`